# .net - open xml sdk - read Excel Pivot values

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

How can I read values from a pivot in Excel?

I think this should be done with Open XML Sdk, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk.

Comment: How do I start to do something questions (like this one), really aren't a good fix for Stackoverflow.  However, as a start, download the OpenXML Productivity Tool from the Microsoft site.  Then create a file that has the Pivot information in it.  Copy the file.  Manually (using Excel) make the changes you want.  Then use the tool's DIFF capabilities to see what happened (from an OpenXML point of view).  The info will likely give you what you need - or at least get you started.

Comment: @Flydog57, the question is not good, but you provided a good answer. Thank you!

Comment: You will find that tool to be useful if you are doing any kind of OpenXML work.